# Linux Debian Jessie sudo command keeps asking for password

Tags: debian, permissions, sudo, nginx, symfony

I have recently configured a Symfony 3 site which involved me to set up some permissions on the `/var` folder. I had to do the following:

```
$ HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo setfacl  -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
```

This added the necessary permissions,
but now I get the following message every time I use the `sudo` command.

```
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for user:
```

This usually is sent only the first time a user uses `sudo`. 
Also, I used to be able to put my password in for `sudo` once and it would expire after some time (and then I would have to re-enter it again). 
Now I get both the massage and prompt for password every time.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Granting the user that runs your web server full read-write permissions to `/var` recursively is an insanely bad idea for security. This is probably why `sudo` is not working right. It stores it's data in `/var`, and is likely now refusing to do so because `/var` is insecure.

Comment: @Patrick is there a better suggestion that could fix my problem. First how do i fix what i messed up. Second how to I give the proper permissions to allow Symfony to do what it needs?

Comment: ? Did you setup sudo ? I.e. there is no default sudo in Debian.

Comment: There is a sudo. Everything was set up just fine working perfectly. I just need to give Symfony the permissions it needed to run. Now things are not working right.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone was wondering this is what I did to fix this problem.

Fix:

```
sudo setfacl -R -b
```

This recursively (-R) removes all (-b) acl permissions

I was also getting a group write warning for the following files:

```
/var/lib/sudo/lectured
/var/lib/sudo/ts
```

Fix:

```
sudo chmod 700
```

for both of the files and that correct the permissions and it fixed the warnings

Answer (score -1):

If you would type

```
sudo -s
```

in the terminal then all command afterward will be executed as `sudo`, but I would not suggest staying in such mode if not necessary.